# Create List out of void Java function?

Tags: java, list, recursion, void

I have two functions. One is a "public static void" one, the other is "public static List" one. The first one is a recursive function. The second one is supposed to collect all the values at the end of each iteration of the first function, until recursion is complete, in a list that will be returned. How should I go about this? I am quite new to Java, although I have had experience in C++ and Python.

Comment: change the returntype and adapt the code. Or, make it store the List as class/instance member

Comment: Try something and when / if you get stuck, post your code and ask for help.

Comment: You could pass the list as a parameter to the recursive method ... show us some code and we can provide better advice. Shouldn't be too hard for your since you already have programming experience.

Comment: It's quite hard to answer a question like this. Could you share some code so we have something concrete to discuss?